# Lumen CSV Reader Cannot Read the 10th or After Columns

Tags: c#, .net, csv

In a nutshell I am using the Lumen CSV reader to try and read CSV data into my program.

I am looping over the columns within a row doing:

```
// open the file "data.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(Path), true))
        {

            string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();

            int RowCount = 1;

            while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
            {

                int TakenValsRowPosCount = 1; //Leave the first value at 0 for weird style

                for (int i = 0; i < csv.FieldCount; i++)
                {

                    if (HeaderstoInput.Contains(headers[i]))
                    {

                        if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(csv[i])) 
                            InputVals[RowCount, TakenValsRowPosCount] = Convert.ToDouble(csv[i]);

                        TakenValsRowPosCount++;

                    }

                }

                RowCount++;

            }

        }
```

For some reason this work perfectly fine until i reaches 10. This value and all values after this are returned as "" (in the watch). Even if there is data there.

I have tried deleting columns from the CSV to shift the 10th column left and reading it and that worked. So it does not seem to be a problem with the data itself, just the 10th and greater columns.

I have tried changing the buffer size in the reader to various values. I cannot seem to find any reference to this problem elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe the reader simply does not support that many columns? Have you checked the documentation or code?

Comment: Hello, I have checked everything I can find and can find no reference to this.

Comment: can you post your entire relevant code?  According to the author's code project site (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader), he tested it on 145 fields (which you can get from the source).

Comment: Can you post some sample data to illustrate the problem?  If not, what us your delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the code, it appears that it assumes that the CSV file has a fixed number of fields, and this is calculated from the fields header or first record read from the file.

How many field are there is the header line? I suspect that there might only be 10 there.

Comment: In my experience having more data columns than header columns causes an index out of range exception.